# Using VLOOKUP with images

Tags: excel, image, vlookup

I am trying to use `VLOOKUP` on a spreadsheet to match images to a selected value.  The formula I'm using is below:

`=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet1!$A$1:$B$42,2,FALSE)`

Right now it returns **0**.  This leads me to believe that in the traditional sense, `VLOOKUP` will *not* return an image.  I have seen other solutions, but they involve smaller sets of image data.  Plus, the workflow seems very labor intensive (involving named cells and the like).  The only workaround I can think of is to have the order of the images match *exactly* the order of the spreadsheet and then use an import tool - like Kutools - to import multiple images.

Is there a (better) solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images are not stored inside an Excel cell and cannot be returned with a formula like Vlookup. Images are stored as objects in a separate layer that sits above the Excel grid.

If you have lots of images that you want to pull/position above a cell dynamically, you will need a different data architecture. Depending on the amount of images, Excel may not be the right tool for the job.